# Sharing data between two aspects in the same program flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

In our Java app, using spring-aop, in order to collect certain statistics, we have two around-advices which get hit consecutively per request, like this: `advice-A ->proceed-> advice-B ->proceed-> advice-B -> advice-A`

To avoid writing to the DB twice, we want to share the information captured by the second advice with the first, and write it all to the DB after the proceed in the first (outer) advice.

How can this be done without using nasty things like static classes with ThreadLocals?

I [read](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-instantiation-models) about `perthis` and `pertarget`, but if I understand it correctly that would only be useful if our service beans are request-scoped. Then you could wire one advice into the other and share information that way.